# Do laws on 'drones' in Australia apply to fixed wing model aircraft?

Tags: fixed-wing, regulations, under-250-grams, rules

I've been looking at the CASA RPA rules (specifically under 250g and under 2kg non-commercial) and there doesn't seem to be a section on fixed-wing aircraft. Do the rules for 'drones' (for instance [these](https://www.casa.gov.au/knowyourdrone/drone-rules)) apply to fixed-wing aircraft. I assume they do but I just want to be sure.

I'm trying to get into model aviation, so expect more of these small questions from me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, "Drone" refers to any unmanned aircraft that can fly autonomously. Usually, however, a drone is classified as any unmanned aircraft even if it requires a remote pilot's  control. By this definition, yes, a fixed wing would be classified as a drone because it is an unmanned aircraft.

Comment: Not sure about CASA, but the CAA in the UK has clarified this to say that 'uncontrolled' object in the air, such as balloons, frizbees, boomerangs and free-flight models are not considered 'aircraft'.

Answer (score 7):

In case you would prefer an answer with citations (as different regulators have different views on this), at the following link is CASA web page regarding "[Recreational unmanned aircraft (including models)](https://www.casa.gov.au/aircraft/sport-aviation/recreational-unmanned-aircraft-including-models-and-drones)". There is a link on this page to the  "... [rules for flying model aircraft and drones.](https://www.casa.gov.au/drones)" - this phrasing demonstrates CASA consider model aircraft and drones to be subject to the same regulations.

However, there are some differences in Australian regulation between commercial and personal/recreational use - follow the links above for the latest information.